# Публикация Play Market Unity

Tags: android, unity3d, playmarket

Ошибка: Вы добавили файл .apk с недействителен подписью (подробнее о подписи). Ошибка apksigner: ERROR: JAR_SIG_NO_MANIFEST: Missing META-INF / MANIFEST.MF

Подготавливаю к выпуску проект ссылаясь на видео: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uIWOqbVuwWU&t=647s

В чем может быть проблема? Может что-то обновить необходимо, не нагуглил решение
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44816305/upload-new-apk-to-alpha-failed

Comment: Может потому что не заполнена строка Confirm keystore password?

Comment: Нет. Проблема была в версии JDK, поставил 8, все работает